# Can't make XML feed work with https even with curl()

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have a php function to fetch featured posts from xml feed. Code can be found below:

```
function getJobsFeed($feed_url) {

$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

$i = 0;

$max_num = 4;

foreach($xml->Item as $entry) {
     echo "<div class='slide'>";
    echo "<h5>$entry->Location</h5>";
    echo "<p>$entry->Title</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='$entry->Link' class='button'>Apply</a>";
    echo "</p></div>";

    if (++$i == $max_num){
        break;
    }
}

}
```

As long as the feed I was using was going through http, everything was alright. Once the feed supplier started using https, it stopped displaying anything on my end.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks,
E.

E:

I realised I wasn't passing the url before. Changed this and problem evolved. Updated code below:

```
function getJobsFeed($feed_url) {




//$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $feed_url);
$result = curl_exec($curl); // $result will contain the XML content 
//curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl); 

echo $result;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

$i = 0;

$max_num = 4;

foreach($xml->Item as $entry) {
     echo "<div class='slide'>";
    echo "<h5>$entry->Location</h5>";
    echo "<p>$entry->Title</p>";
    echo "<p><a href='$entry->Link' class='button button--crimson'>Apply</a>";
    echo "</p></div>";

    if (++$i == $max_num){
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Now I'm getting the following error:

Invalid URL

The requested URL "/feeds/datafeed.ashx?featured=true&format=xml", is invalid.
Reference #9.86cd417.1434453158.409d8a2

Just in case - I can check the url and the feed is there, so that's not the problem.

contents of curl_getinfo:

Array ( [url] => provided_link [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 400 [header_size] => 210 [request_size] => 105 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.305444 [namelookup_time] => 0.150466 [connect_time] => 0.15239 [pretransfer_time] => 0.303479 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 260 [speed_download] => 851 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 260 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.305407 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => primary_ip_here [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => local_ip_here [local_port] => 34340 [redirect_url] => )

Not sure if this changes anything, but the location I take feed from is currently in staging phase, so only accessible once I update my hosts with provided ip and domain. Just to clarify... My hosts ARE currently updated with required information.

Comment: try curl_getinfo($curl); before curl_close() called and post the data you receive in info.

Comment: var_dump or print_r the array contents

Comment: @ValentinRusk updated the question with the curl_getinfo contents

Comment: *The requested URL "/feeds/datafeed.ashx?featured=true&format=xml", is invalid. Reference #9.86cd417.1434453158.409d8a2* - That's pretty straightforward. Encrypted URLs start with `https:`, not `/...`. :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  After MrCode spotted that I wasn't declaring my useragent in proper way, I've updated it and returned 'faulty url' that starts with https. Moreover, after pasting said url in the browser it's taking me straight to the working feed. Not quite sure problem lies in my code, because I tried it on normal http link and everything is working just fine. Only thing I'm not sure about now, is the thing I mentioned in my last edit - the location I take feed from is currently in staging phase, so only accessible once I update my hosts with provided ip and domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user agent definition isn't right, you've missed the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` part of the call.

Change to:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
//                 ^ was missing
```

The server is returning a 400 Bad Request response, most likely because you weren't providing a user agent header – some web servers require this.

Comment: I updated it and now it's returning the faulty url in a proper way (starting from https, while before it was returning incorrect link). Thanks for that!